# How Can I send files to Xiomi Mi 4i

Tags: transfer

I tried connecting my new Xiaomi Mi 4i via USB. Its mounted and all, everything was fine till i tried to copy some files to the phone. It says the device is "Read-only." Now Xiaomi says their file transfer interface is for Windows only and not Ubuntu. Can someone please suggest some way to transfer my files?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I kind of stumbled upon an almost too obvious solution.

I can just connect a flash drive or external HDD using an **OTG cable**. Cables are available readily at any local store for about a dollar. No setup is required.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VUhFKJgqqQ

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to send files to a mobile device.

**Method 1:**

> *Prerequisites:*
>
> adb is to be [installed](http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378) on the Ubuntu system and Developer mode is to be [enabled](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42) on the device

You could [push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20834609/773226) the files to your mobile device through the terminal.

**Method 2:**

There are various applications available in Play Store like [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en), [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en) etc which helps with graphical file copy interfaces and are pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I've had 2 Xiaomi and never had any issue (specially compared to windows!). Make sure your cable allows transferring data (not only charging). Alternatively, you can use [Gsconnect](https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki) to transfer things wirelessly.